# Android Retrofit - GoogleBooksAPI - JSON return issue

Tags: android, retrofit, google-books

I'm trying to make my android app to return book info using the google book API. Here's the [url I'm pinging](https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=enders%20game) I'm using retrofit to grab the info and bring it back to me however it's coming back like this and I'm not sure how to resolve it:

```
D/MainActivity2: onResponse: Success
    onResponse: success body: models.Book2@ae8dded
    onResponse: success response: Response{protocol=h2, code=200, message=, url=https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=enders+game}
    onResponse: success raw: Response{protocol=h2, code=200, message=, url=https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=enders+game}
    onResponse: success code: 200
D/MainActivity2: onResponse: success getItems: [models.Book2$Items@b12e422, models.Book2$Items@cd9aeb3, models.Book2$Items@d5c1c70, models.Book2$Items@f826be9, models.Book2$Items@69f206e, models.Book2$Items@b6830f, models.Book2$Items@63e8f9c, models.Book2$Items@70cdda5, models.Book2$Items@ea0d57a, models.Book2$Items@1e2412b]
```

here's the code block I'm using to grab it:

```
    private void parseJson3(String key){
        // source = https://medium.com/@wkrzywiec/making-use-of-open-rest-api-with-retrofit-dac6094f0522
        //  youtube tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4JGvDUlfk7Y


        JsonPlaceHolderApi serviceEndPoint = ServiceGenerator.createService(JsonPlaceHolderApi.class);



        Call<Book2> call = serviceEndPoint.getQueryItems2("volumes?q=enders+game");
//        Call<Book2Items> call = serviceEndPoint.getQueryItems("volumes?q=enders+game");
//        Call<Book2List> call = serviceEndPoint.getQuery2("volumes?q=enders+game");
//        Call<BookList> call = serviceEndPoint.getQuery1("enders+game");


        call.enqueue(new Callback<Book2>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Book2> call, retrofit2.Response<Book2> response) {

                if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                    String title ="";
//                List<String> author = "";
                    String author =" ";
                    String publishedDate = "Not Available";
                    String publisher = "Not Available";
                    String description = "No Description";
                    int pageCount = 1000;
                    String category = "No categories Available ";
                    String buy ="";
//                String volumeInfoString = "";
                    String bookJSONString = null;
                    String thumbnail = "";
                    String previewLink = "";
                    String price = "";
                    String url = "";


//                for (int i = 0; i < grantResults.length; i++) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.body().getItems().size(); i++) {


                        Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: success getmTitle: " + response.body().getItems().get(i).getVolumeInfo().getmTitle());
                        title = response.body().getItems().get(i).getVolumeInfo().getmTitle();
                        Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: success getmAuthors: " + response.body().getItems().get(i).getVolumeInfo().getmAuthors());
//                    author = response.body().getItems().get(i).getVolumeInfo().getmAuthors();
                        Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: success getmCategories: " + response.body().getItems().get(i).getVolumeInfo().getmCategories());
//                    category = response.body().getItems().get(i).getVolumeInfo().getmCategories();
                        Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: success getmDescription: " + response.body().getItems().get(i).getVolumeInfo().getmDescription());
                        description = response.body().getItems().get(i).getVolumeInfo().getmDescription();
                        Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: success getmPublisher: " + response.body().getItems().get(i).getVolumeInfo().getmPublisher());
                        publisher = response.body().getItems().get(i).getVolumeInfo().getmPublisher();
                        Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: success getmImageLinks: " + response.body().getItems().get(i).getVolumeInfo().getmImageLinks().getmThumbnail());
                        thumbnail = response.body().getItems().get(i).getVolumeInfo().getmImageLinks().getmThumbnail();
                    }

                    Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: title = " + title);


                    mBooks.add(new Book2(title, author, publishedDate, description ,category
                            , thumbnail, buy, previewLink, price, pageCount, url));


                    mSearchViewRecyclerViewAdapter = new SearchViewRecyclerViewAdapter(MainActivity2.this , mBooks);
                    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mSearchViewRecyclerViewAdapter);

                } else {

                    Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: call in MainActivity2 was not successful");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Book2> call, Throwable t) {

                Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: didnt work" + t);
            }
        });
    }
```

here is my **Book2** model with the getters and setters:

```
    public class Book2 {

    @SerializedName("items")
    private List<Items> items;

    public Book2() {
        // no arg constructor needed
    }

    public Book2(Items items) {

    }

    public List<Items> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(List<Items> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    public class Items {

        @SerializedName("volumeInfo")
        private VolumeInfo volumeInfo;


        public VolumeInfo getVolumeInfo() {
            return volumeInfo;
        }

        public void setVolumeInfo(VolumeInfo volumeInfo) {
            this.volumeInfo = volumeInfo;
        }
    }


    public class VolumeInfo {

        @SerializedName("title")
        private String mTitle;

        @SerializedName("authors")
        private ArrayList<String> mAuthors;

        @SerializedName("publisher")
        private String mPublisher;

        @SerializedName("publishedDate")
        private String mPublishedDate;

        @SerializedName("description")
        private String mDescription;

//        @SerializedName("industryIdentifiers")
//        private ArrayList<String> mIndustryIdentifiers;

        @SerializedName("categories")
        private ArrayList<String> mCategories;

        @SerializedName("imageLinks")
        private ImageLinks mImageLinks;




        public String getmTitle() {
            return mTitle;
        }

        public void setmTitle(String mTitle) {
            this.mTitle = mTitle;
        }

        public ArrayList<String> getmAuthors() {
            return mAuthors;
        }

        public void setmAuthors(ArrayList<String> mAuthors) {
            this.mAuthors = mAuthors;
        }

        public String getmPublisher() {
            return mPublisher;
        }

        public void setmPublisher(String mPublisher) {
            this.mPublisher = mPublisher;
        }

        public String getmPublishedDate() {
            return mPublishedDate;
        }

        public void setmPublishedDate(String mPublishedDate) {
            this.mPublishedDate = mPublishedDate;
        }

        public String getmDescription() {
            return mDescription;
        }

        public void setmDescription(String mDescription) {
            this.mDescription = mDescription;
        }

/*
        public ArrayList<String> getmIndustryIdentifiers() {
            return mIndustryIdentifiers;
        }

        public void setmIndustryIdentifiers(ArrayList<String> mIndustryIdentifiers) {
            this.mIndustryIdentifiers = mIndustryIdentifiers;
        }

 */

        public ArrayList<String> getmCategories() {
            return mCategories;
        }

        public void setmCategories(ArrayList<String> mCategories) {
            this.mCategories = mCategories;
        }


        public ImageLinks getmImageLinks() {
            return mImageLinks;
        }

        public void setmImageLinks(ImageLinks mImageLinks) {
            this.mImageLinks = mImageLinks;
        }
    }

    public class ImageLinks {
        @SerializedName("thumbnail")
        private String mThumbnail;

        public String getmThumbnail() {
            return mThumbnail;
        }

        public void setmThumbnail(String mThumbnail) {
            this.mThumbnail = mThumbnail;
        }
    }


}
```

**MainActivity2**

```
public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {


    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private ArrayList<Book2> mBooks;
    private SearchViewRecyclerViewAdapter mSearchViewRecyclerViewAdapter;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

    private static  final  String BASE_URL2="https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/";
    private static  final  String BASE_URL_TYPICODE="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/";
//    private static  final  String BASE_URL="https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=";


    private EditText search_edit_text;
    Button search_button;
    ProgressBar loading_indicator;
    private TextView error_message;

//    private static final String LOG_TAG = MainActivity2.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity2";



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_book_main2);

        search_edit_text=findViewById(R.id.search_box);
        search_button= findViewById(R.id.search_buttton);
        loading_indicator=findViewById(R.id.loading_indicator);
        error_message= findViewById(R.id.message_display);

        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        mBooks = new ArrayList<>();
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);


        search_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mBooks.clear();
                search();
            }
        });
    }

   private void parseJson3(String key){
        // source = https://medium.com/@wkrzywiec/making-use-of-open-rest-api-with-retrofit-dac6094f0522
        //  youtube tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4JGvDUlfk7Y


        JsonPlaceHolderApi serviceEndPoint = ServiceGenerator.createService(JsonPlaceHolderApi.class);



        Call<Book2> call = serviceEndPoint.getQueryItems2("volumes?q=enders+game");
//        Call<Book2Items> call = serviceEndPoint.getQueryItems("volumes?q=enders+game");
//        Call<Book2List> call = serviceEndPoint.getQuery2("volumes?q=enders+game");
//        Call<BookList> call = serviceEndPoint.getQuery1("enders+game");


        call.enqueue(new Callback<Book2>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Book2> call, retrofit2.Response<Book2> response) {

                if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                    String title ="";
//                List<String> author = "";
                    String author =" ";
                    String publishedDate = "Not Available";
                    String publisher = "Not Available";
                    String description = "No Description";
                    int pageCount = 1000;
                    String category = "No categories Available ";
                    String buy ="";
//                String volumeInfoString = "";
                    String bookJSONString = null;
                    String thumbnail = "";
                    String previewLink = "";
                    String price = "";
                    String url = "";


//                for (int i = 0; i < grantResults.length; i++) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.body().getItems().size(); i++) {


                        Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: success getmTitle: " + response.body().getItems().get(i).getVolumeInfo().getmTitle());
                        title = response.body().getItems().get(i).getVolumeInfo().getmTitle();
                        Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: success getmAuthors: " + response.body().getItems().get(i).getVolumeInfo().getmAuthors());
//                    author = response.body().getItems().get(i).getVolumeInfo().getmAuthors();
                        Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: success getmCategories: " + response.body().getItems().get(i).getVolumeInfo().getmCategories());
//                    category = response.body().getItems().get(i).getVolumeInfo().getmCategories();
                        Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: success getmDescription: " + response.body().getItems().get(i).getVolumeInfo().getmDescription());
                        description = response.body().getItems().get(i).getVolumeInfo().getmDescription();
                        Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: success getmPublisher: " + response.body().getItems().get(i).getVolumeInfo().getmPublisher());
                        publisher = response.body().getItems().get(i).getVolumeInfo().getmPublisher();
                        Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: success getmImageLinks: " + response.body().getItems().get(i).getVolumeInfo().getmImageLinks().getmThumbnail());
                        thumbnail = response.body().getItems().get(i).getVolumeInfo().getmImageLinks().getmThumbnail();
                    }

                    Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: title = " + title);


//                    mBooks.add(new Book2(title, author, publishedDate, description ,category
//                            , thumbnail, buy, previewLink, price, pageCount, url));

                    mBooks.add(new Book2());


                    mSearchViewRecyclerViewAdapter = new SearchViewRecyclerViewAdapter(MainActivity2.this , mBooks);
                    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mSearchViewRecyclerViewAdapter);

                } else {

                    Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: call in MainActivity2 was not successful");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Book2> call, Throwable t) {

                Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: didnt work" + t);
            }
        });
    }

private boolean Read_network_state(Context context)
    {    boolean is_connected;
        ConnectivityManager cm =(ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo info = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        is_connected=info!=null&&info.isConnectedOrConnecting();
        return is_connected;
    }


    private void search()
    {
        String search_query = search_edit_text.getText().toString();

        boolean is_connected = Read_network_state(this);
        if(!is_connected)
        {
            error_message.setText(R.string.Failed_to_Load_data);
            mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            error_message.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            return;
        }

        //  Log.d("QUERY",search_query);


        if(search_query.equals(""))
        {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Please enter your query",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        String final_query=search_query.replace(" ","+");

        Uri uri=Uri.parse(BASE_URL2+final_query);
//        Uri uri=Uri.parse(BASE_URL+final_query);
        Uri.Builder buider = uri.buildUpon();

        parseJson3(buider.toString());


    }


}
```

**SearchViewRecyclerViewAdapter.java**

```
public class SearchViewRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SearchViewRecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<Book2> mData;
    private RequestOptions options;
    private static final String LOG_TAG = SearchViewRecyclerViewAdapter.class.getSimpleName();


    public SearchViewRecyclerViewAdapter(Context mContext, List<Book2> mData) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mData = mData;

        //Request option for Glide
        options = new RequestOptions().centerCrop().placeholder(R.drawable.loading_shape).error(R.drawable.loading_shape);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int i) {

        View view;
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.book_raw_item2 , parent , false);
        final MyViewHolder viewHolder =  new MyViewHolder(view);
        viewHolder.container.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(mContext , BookProfileActivity2.class);
                int pos = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
//                i.putExtra("book_title" ,mData.get(pos).getTitle());
                i.putExtra("book_author" ,mData.get(pos).getAuthors());
//                i.putExtra("book_desc" ,mData.get(pos).getDescription());
                i.putExtra("book_categories" ,mData.get(pos).getCategories());
                i.putExtra("book_publish_date" ,mData.get(pos).getPublishedDate());
                i.putExtra("book_info" ,mData.get(pos).getmUrl());
                i.putExtra("book_buy" ,mData.get(pos).getBuy());
                i.putExtra("book_preview" ,mData.get(pos).getPerview());
                i.putExtra("book_thumbnail" ,mData.get(pos).getThumbnail());
//                i.putExtra("volumeInfo" ,mData.get(pos).getVolumeInfo());

//                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onClick: " + mData.get(pos).getVolumeInfo());


                mContext.startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int i) {

        Book2 book = mData.get(i);
//        holder.tvTitle.setText(book.getTitle());
        holder.tvAuthor.setText(book.getAuthors());
        holder.tvPrice.setText(book.getPrice());
        holder.tvCategory.setText(book.getCategories());

        //load image from internet and set it into imageView using Glide
        Glide.with(mContext).load(book.getThumbnail()).apply(options).into(holder.ivThumbnail);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        ImageView ivThumbnail ;
        TextView tvTitle , tvCategory , tvPrice , tvAuthor;
        LinearLayout container ;
        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            ivThumbnail = itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
            tvTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            tvAuthor = itemView.findViewById(R.id.author);
            tvCategory = itemView.findViewById(R.id.category);
            tvPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.price);
            container = itemView.findViewById(R.id.container);


        }
    }
}
```

any and all help and direction is appreciated. if downvote is your choice, please give a reason.

Comment: What is mBooks ? you can use response.body().getItems() and pass this to the adapter.

Comment: Post Your adapter class

Comment: @KaushalPanchal i've posted the adapter class.

Comment: @Swayangjit currently im just trying to get the JSON to read out correctly and pull the content from the url. i dont know what the stuff like "models.Book2$Items@b12e422" is.

Comment: Just pass it to the adpter and check if its working or not.

Comment: @Swayangjit  isn't that going to give me the same response as posted above at the response.body().getItems())? I thought the array im getting back is the title authors, publisher, etc.

Comment: so I was able to get this working but it requires a specific index. at the get(0) part 'Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: success getItems: "response.body().getItems().get(0).getVolumeInfo().getmTitle());'

Comment: Do you have to retrieve the title and author's rights?

Comment: Please tell us what you have to achieve?

Comment: @KaushalPanchal I was just trying to get the information from URL that I posted in the question. i've created a for loop to grab the titles which now works. now I just need to grab the rest of the information and pass it to the adapter so it can be displayed. i'll post my answer once ive finished fleshing it out.

Comment: @KaushalPanchal, I created a new question since my code changed a fair amount. see link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58406028/android-google-books-api-how-to-pass-retrofit-response-to-recyclerviewadapter)